# How to include php code on a page in octobercms?

Tags: octobercms

I want to run a simple php script on a page in Octobercms. I tried that:

```
<?php echo 123; phpinfo(); ?>
```

and that:

```
{% echo 123; phpinfo(); %}
```

didn't work. How to include a script on a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

October's CMS pages are only able to execute functions. So for your above example, you need to go to the 'Code' tab and in there write:

```
function onStart() { echo 123; echo phpinfo(); }
```

Alternatively, if you are wanting to pass a value, like "123", you can set a variable in the onStart() function and then just call that variable on the page. Like this:

```
function onStart() { 
    $this["myVar"] = "123";
    }
```

And then where you want that variable on the CMS page, you write:

```
{{ myVar }}
```

Comment: I didnt know about **Code tab**, that is what I found https://octobercms.com/forum/post/what-for-is-code-tab-beside-markup-tab-in-cms-section-of-the-backend